# Automatically build SWC after save in FDT4

Tags: flash, apache-flex, ide, flash-builder, fdt

I'm currently trying FDT 4 for Flash/Flex development (was using Flash Builder) before, but I have a little annoyance.

I have two projects: GameCommon and GameWeb. GameCommon is a library, compiled to an SWC file, while GameWeb is a thin wrapper around that SWC and is compiled to an SWF (There's also a project GameDesktop which is an AIR wrapper around the SWC).

In Flash builder, the SWC would automatically get built when I edit and something in GameCommon, meaning that if I ran GameWeb afterwards, it would be updated.

In FDT however, I have to explicitly run a launcher to get it to build the SWC for GameCommon (after which it will automatically rebuild GameWeb). Is there a way to change this so it works more like Flash Builder?

Answer (score 1):

Currently FDT does not have a library project which automatically saves a SWC for the whole project. You could trigger the launcher for the SWC by adding it to the launcher chain of the launchers which compile the SWFs.
You can find a tutorial on using the launcher chain here: http://www.fdt.powerflasher.com/developer-tools/fdt/whats-new/

Comment: I've tried that but that just causes the SWC to be compiled, then the SWF. This is what already happens when I compile the SWC, and the SWF is not run in the same chain (even though the launcher is normally a runner).